# Running gstreamer app in OpenVino using Windows subsystem in Linux (WSL2)

Tags: openvino

My system main OS is  Windows-10 OS and installed WSL2 in subsystem.

Openvino is installed in Linux under WSL2. The reason is dlstreamer-gst is supported only in linux.

When I test the following test app, it works only for fps and display is not working.

If I run app as

```
./vehicle_pedestrian_tracking.sh person-bicycle-car-detection.mp4 10 CPU fps
```

I can see the output as

```
FpsCounter(1sec): total=346.54 fps, number-streams=1, per-stream=346.54 fps
FPSCounter(average): total=340.06 fps, number-streams=1, per-stream=340.06 fps
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:02.456260800
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

When I run for display,

```
./vehicle_pedestrian_tracking.sh person-bicycle-car-detection.mp4 10 CPU dispaly
```

I have error as

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: Could not initialise Xv output
Additional debug info:
../sys/xvimage/xvimagesink.c(1778): gst_xv_image_sink_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
Could not open display (null)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Failed to set pipeline to PAUSED.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Is it display is not available in WSL subsystem?

Comment: I am following this discussion using X server in `https://research.wmz.ninja/articles/2017/11/setting-up-wsl-with-graphics-and-audio.html` and `https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx`. But still can't

Answer (score 1):

Use [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html) with WSL2 and change the command of `xvimagesink` to `ximagesink` in *vehicle_pedestrian_tracking.sh*.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is I can't display but I can save to file as

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video1.avi ! decodebin ! video/x-raw ! queue ! gvadetect model=/home/nyan/intel/dl_streamer/models/intel/vehicle-detection/FP16/model_fp16.xml model-proc=./model_proc/vehicle-detection.json inference-interval=10 threshold=0.6 device=CPU ! queue ! gvafpscounter ! filesink location=output.avi
```